# Is there a method in Java that allows me to replace all HTML special characters into their encoded equivelant?

Tags: java, html, encoding

I have a textfile which my Java program is modifying and putting into an HTML file for display.

However, this textfile contains lots of HTML unsafe characters such as "<" and the ">" which would need to be encoded into  `& gt;` (sans space) and `& lt;`.

Is there some library method I can use to sanatize my text document to replace all these HTML special characters with their safe encoded equivelants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [escapeHtml](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build your own, it is fairly easy using the String replace method, you just need a list of targets and replacements, and bam, you're done.

[replace(CharSequence target,
                      CharSequence replacement)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)